# i7 6700 + ASRock Fatal1ty ITX/ac = can't install any operating system

Tags: windows-installation, intel-core-i7

My configuration is:

- mobo: Fatal1ty Z170 Gaming-ITX/ac
- cpu: i7 6700 (SN: M592301Y01849, Batch: L543B896, product code: BX80662176700)
- ram: G.Skill F4-3000C15D-32GTZ
- ssd: Samsung 850 Pro 512GB,SATA
- no external video card.

I have a problem with "freezing"/hanging up.

1. In case of Windows:

   1. During Windows installation on loader's page after 1/4 part of circle animation everything freezes and cant do anything. Computer is not responding.
   2. I've tried to boot up a computer from my previous computer (Win10x64) but everything freezed on loader screen also.
      By loader screen I mean black screen with win logo and circle animation below.
2. In case of Linux (Ubuntu):
   After that I chose something on grub screen (Try without installation or install) screen become black and only cursor blinks.

I've tried to install both Windows and Ubuntu from bootable USB and from borrowed DVD drive also - result is the same.

Have you ever heard about similar issue?
I've tried to disable/enable many suspicious things in UEFI but without success.
I've also tested memory in memtest - everything OK.

One guy from ASRock support told me:

> If the installation stops at a certain point, it means that it found
>   hardware that it cannot activate. Intel has used different graphics in
>   the 6700 CPU. I know this, because one of our resellers used this CPU,
>   and created an Image to quickly install Windows10 It always worked,
>   until he received a new batch of 6700 CPU’s, and suddenly his image
>   didn’t work anymore, only if he inserted a graphics card, it would
>   work fine. Intel doesn’t mention anything, but to me it is clear they
>   make modifications to the CPU’s, there is no other explanation.

I received new mobo tommorow but the issue still exists. I also tried with kingston memories, without luck.
Could it be something with CPU? I dont have any additional devices connected to computer. Disconnecting SSD results the same - loader scree of windows hangs.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu did you try to install?

Comment: Latest one - 16.04

Comment: That's strange. I can only recommend you unplug everything you possible can to see if it boots.

Comment: Yes. That's really strange. Unfortunately I tried that - same result.

Comment: Is it too late to return the CPU and motherboard for exchange?

Comment: I installed external graphics and it works! That implies the problem is with integrated graphics in CPU and mobo compatibility. I suppose that many people could have the same problem but usually ppl buy external graphics so problem is not visible for them. Also after drivers installation and updates Win when I unplug gpu the problem remains. One more thing: Problem is not only with my cpu because service guy from hardware shop tried different cpus i3 and i5 and the issue was visible also. Unfortunately Asrock support can't reporoduce that issue.

Comment: that would point to a problematic motherboard then, I think. Although, I guess as long as it works with a dedicated GPU, you're good. If you can get a warranty replacement for the board, I would do it, just in case it completely breaks later on.

Comment: Unfortunately no. I've replaced mobo twice (warranty replacement). Same issue. Maybe someone in the future find this thread and it will be helpful for him.